# What are the most effective methods for monitoring changes in polygon layers over time

Tags: change-detection

I work with many different thematic areas with GIS but there is one underlying task which as yet has never been satisfactorily methodized. This is how to effectively monitor changes over time. Particularly in the areas of Landuse planning and Environmental programs there is the need to analyse how layers have changed since the last update. Non-GIS users want a simple understandable method to viusalise and document change but is often very complex in nature. Usually my method involves geoprocessing tools such as "union"  or "identify" with ArcGIS to save old and new features in the same feature class and start the analysis from there. This method is however sometimes difficult for non-GIS users to understand and then to query. 
What are the most effective methods for monitoring changes using GIS?

Comment: Raster-based analysis is usually the most effective way to monitor change. Dealing with pixel values is much more efficient and effective than working with vector data and their associated attributes.

Comment: For vector data, I tend to use the **Difference** tool in QGIS (I think the ArcGIS equivalent is [Symmetrical Difference](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Symmetrical%20Difference%20%28Analysis%29)). When using the tool on the old and new layers, the output will contain polygons which shows how the old layer was updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaron is right about raster- based analysis. There are a lot of methods for change detection.One very popular method is the Post-classification Comparison. I think the effectiveness of a method is related to the application you want (e.g vegetation change), so I am not sure if there is one method that is more efficient than the others. Some of them (http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0143116031000139863) are:

[image]